# Spark SQL - does renaming columns affect partitioning?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have written an explicitJoin API which renames the columns in a Dataset with either a l_ or r_ prefix to disambiguate and to solve problems with spark lineage, i.e columnName1#77 not found in columnName1#123, columnName2#55....

Part of the code is shown below:

```
 def explicitJoin(other: Dataset[_], joinExpr: Column, joinType: String): ExplicitJoinExt = {
  val left = dataset.toDF(dataset.columns.map("l_" + _): _*)
  val right = other.toDF(other.columns.map("r_" + _): _*)

  new ExplicitJoinExt(left.join(right, joinExpr, joinType))
}
```

Users may then pass a join expressions such as $"l_columnName1" === $"r_columnName1" && ... so that they are 100% explicit about what columns they are joining on.

I am experiencing a new issue where partitions are too large to load into memory (org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Too large frame....) yet there was no problem reading the input (partitioned) Datasets.

Can renaming columns affect the underlying parititioning of the input Datasets/DataFrames?

**EDIT**

**Example 1 - regular join**

```
    case class A(a: Int, b: String)

    val l = (0 to 1000000).map(i => A(i, i.toString))
    val r = (0 to 1000000).map(i => A(i, i.toString))

    val ds1 = l.toDF.as[A].repartition(100, $"a")
    val ds2 = r.toDF.as[A].repartition(100, $"a")

    val joined = ds1.join(ds2, Seq("a"), "inner")

    joined.explain

    == Physical Plan ==
    *Project [a#2, b#3, b#15]
    +- *SortMergeJoin [a#2], [a#14], Inner
       :- *Sort [a#2 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
       :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(a#2, 100)
       :     +- LocalTableScan [a#2, b#3]
       +- *Sort [a#14 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
          +- ReusedExchange [a#14, b#15], Exchange hashpartitioning(a#2, 100)
```

**Example 2 - Using my (possibly misguided) ExplicitJoinExt involving renames**

```
    val joined = ds1
      .explicitJoin(ds2, $"l_a" === $"r_a", "inner") // Pimped on conversion to ExplicitJoin type, columns prefixed by l_ or r_. DS joined by expr and join type
      .selectLeft                                    // Select just left prefixed columns
      .toDF                                          // Convert back from ExplicitJoinExpr to DF
      .as[A]

    joined.explain


    == Physical Plan ==
    *Project [l_a#24 AS a#53, l_b#25 AS b#54]
    +- *BroadcastHashJoin [l_a#24], [r_a#29], Inner, BuildRight
       :- *Project [a#2 AS l_a#24, b#3 AS l_b#25]
       :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(a#2, 100)
       :     +- LocalTableScan [a#2, b#3]
       +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, false] as bigint)))
          +- *Project [a#14 AS r_a#29]
             +- Exchange hashpartitioning(a#14, 100)
                +- LocalTableScan [a#14]
```

So, for the second join it would apear that we are repartitioning again - correct?

Answer (score 0):

NO, I checked in SPARK 2.3.1. Renaming does not affect partitioning, at least not in this approach:

```
 val ds11 = ds1.repartition(4)
```

NO, I checked this also. Renaming does not affect partitioning, at least not in this approach:

```
 val ds11 = ds1.repartition(2, $"cityid")
```

EXPLAIN Output for:

```
val j = left.join(right, $"l_personid" === $"r_personid", "inner").explain
```

​reveals, in my case 2 and 4 as number of partitions:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) BroadcastHashJoin [l_personid#641], [r_personid#647], Inner, 
BuildRight, false
:- *(2) Project [personid#612 AS l_personid#641, personname#613 AS 
l_personname#642, cityid#614 AS l_cityid#643]
:  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(cityid#614, 2)
:     +- LocalTableScan [personid#612, personname#613, cityid#614]   
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, false] as bigint)))
   +- *(1) Project [personid#612 AS r_personid#647, personname#613 AS r_personname#648, cityid#614 AS r_cityid#649]
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(personid#612, 4)
         +- LocalTableScan [personid#612, personname#613, cityid#614]
```

One can see that the renamed cols are mapped back to their original names.

In a test on a post elsewhere we were able to ascertain that new actions relying on AGGRegations or JOINs will default to 200 unless

```
 sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "some val")
```

is issued in the code setting this to the required value. If it is a small set of data being JOINed, etc. then the results may differ.

Comment: My concern is that I am partitioning on (say) joinKey1 on both DS prior to the join but renaming to l_joinKey1 and r_joinKey 1 before joining on $"l_joinKey1" === $"r_joinKey1" - Is Spark cleve enough to realise the data is already partitioned and colocated on the original column name?

Comment: I checked the scenarios (during lunch) and found the partitioning is inherited in terms of numbers, not 200 as per default. I infer that there is no issue. Did you try an explain? on before and after changing names?

Comment: This question: Can renaming columns affect the underlying parititioning of the input Datasets/DataFrames?, I believe has been answered.

Comment: As can be clearly seen in explain, the renamed cols map back to the original ones. The partitioning I applied originally remains in effect.

Answer (score 0):

For those still encountering this issue: renaming columns does affect partitioning in Spark < 3.0.

```
Seq((1, 2))
  .toDF("a", "b")
  .repartition($"b")
  .withColumnRenamed("b", "c")
  .repartition($"c")
  .explain()
```

Gives the following plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
Exchange hashpartitioning(c#40, 10)
+- *(1) Project [a#36, b#37 AS c#40]
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(b#37, 10)
      +- LocalTableScan [a#36, b#37]
```

This was fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/26943).